# Can I Recover Email Address That Have Been Signed Into On My Galaxy Phone??

Tags: data-recovery

When I factory reset my phone, it had signed me out of my Gmail account that I had created and used for my Google Play Store. And now I cannot remember what the exact email address was.

It has my SMS backup and restore on it and all of my pictures and contacts and important info. Is there a way to find out what the email address was??

Answer (score 1):

All account data on the phone is lost after a factory reset. Perhaps you can use a different way to find that email address, however.

- Did you ever send email from that account to one of your other email
  accounts? What about to a friend or family member? See if you can find one
  of those old messages.
- Did you ever log into a Google service using that account on a PC/Mac
  browser? If so, maybe you can find it in your browsing history or
  saved passwords.
- Did you link that Google account with any other online service? Did
  you create a Google+ account with that address? You might have if you
  ever wrote a review of an app in the Google Play store. Try and find your Google+ profile.